# How to use Integral Symbol in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-edittext

I am currently busy on my formula app. The UI is completely ready. All I need to do is just put formulas in it. But I am having trouble in some math formulae with the Integration, differenciation, and some other symbols like division and all that.

I don't want to have the images as they increase the size of app. 
Please help me specially for the division symbol. 
(Not  like   /    or   ÷   )

Answer (score -3):

The division symbol in java is /  ...such as 9/3=3.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

Could you be more specific?

Oh, and to all those downvoters out there, perhaps you need to stop and try to help rather than throw a vote without reading...

Comment: I mean I want to have the symbol like. A on B. That big line between A and B.    You understand what I said

Comment: If you are just going for the appearance of the fraction, and not functionality, you could make a vertical LinearLayout with multiple text fields and use setText to give the appearance of A over B

Comment: Or if you need help with programmatically setting math, you could use http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/fraction.html

Comment: I don't want the functionality I just want the view in string.xml so that I can include it in my formula list view

Comment: If you need something in your string xml I would use this, I must be misunderstanding <string name="division">-</string> otherwise you probably will need to add a picture to do exactly what you need to.